# What to do to flash to device after building android source code?

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, android-source, android-build

So I built the Android `10.0.0_r2` source on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM over Google Compute Engine for  `aosp_arm` and then I was provided with a lot of `.zip`s and `.img`s in `/out/target/product/generic`.

And now, I have no idea how to flash it to a device! For some reason, fastboot is no longer working on my device. I expected a `.zip` that I could flash via TWRP recovery, but there a lot other images instead. After searching a lot, I ran the following commands:

```
# first, build the target-files .zip
. build/envsetup.sh && lunch tardis-eng
mkdir dist_output
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output

./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files dist_output/aosp_arm-target_files.zip ota_update.zip
```

But received an error saying

`target build has specified no recovery`

So, can anyone tell me how to get rid of this error, or preferably, how to go about flashing the various images and zips, and which ones?

I'd be really grateful.